# Копировать в буфер с формы

Tags: javascript

Есть форма

```
echo "<input type='text' value='Мой текст' />";
```

Мне нужно сделать такую кнопку, чтобы, при нажатии на нее, текст, который в форме, копировался в буфер обмена.

Comment: В нормальных браузерах JavaScript'у запрещено оперировать с буфером обмена, потому что это не безопасно. Flash также работает не у всех. Его нет на планшетах, у кого-то стоит flashBlock, у кого-то системный администратор отключил. В общем случае не стоит рассчитывать на возможность работы с буфером обмена. Только предложить пользователю скопировать самому, как сделано в документах Google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```js
var button = document.querySelector('.copy');
button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var text = document.querySelector('.text');
  text.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
});
```

```html
<input class="text" type='text' value='Мой текст' />
<button class="copy">Копировать</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если задачу необходимо решить при помощи JavaScript (например нужна поддержка платформ, где нет Adobe Flash), стоит смотреть в сторону функции [Document.execCommand('copy')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand). В этом случае, придётся почитать спецификации браузеров на предмет поддержки Document.execCommand и подумать о том, как не сломать код на старых браузерах. Тяжкий труд :)

Если нет жёстких ограничений на использование Adobe Flash в проекте, я рекомендовал бы использовать готовое решение вроде этого: [ZeroClipboard](http://zeroclipboard.org/). Оно использует для работы с буфером невидимый Flash, причём работа с флэшовым компонентом происходит через JavaScript-интерфейс. На страничке проекта на [Github](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard) есть примеры использования.